# Excel VBA Picture Insert Not Working - Only for Some URLs

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have used the below VBA code to insert pictures from an image URL. 
For some reason, this code works with some image URLs but not for others.

For example, the below URLs will work

http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/3123076.png&w=350&h=254

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/David_Njoku_2018.jpg/220px-David_Njoku_2018.jpg

But the below will not

http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41HkOMYqc9L.SL500.jpg

http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41gWzC%2B5IqL.SL500.jpg

http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41gWzC%2B5IqL.SL500.jpg

Does anyone know if there are any limitations to the  "ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert" command?

Below is the code i am using

```
Sub URLPictureInsert()
    Dim Pshp As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1 :A24")
    For Each cell In Rng
        filenam = cell
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
        Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
        If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
        xCol = cell.Column + 1
        Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
        With Pshp
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 100
            .Height = 100
            .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
            .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
        End With
lab:
    Set Pshp = Nothing
    Range("A1").Select
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that the images that *don't* work are all from `images-amazon.com`. Perhaps there's something the they are implementing that doesn't allow you to access the image like you're calling it.  Perhaps save the image locally, then use the local file as what to insert?  In other words - let's try and figure out if it's a limitation with your VBA code, or the image/source itself.

Comment: I would try debugging this code to see how the code perceives the URL. It could be some of the characters in them. Or it could be that Amazon doesn't let you use VBA code with its images as a security thing.

Comment: I actually have the same issue with the same procedure (same source ?! :-) ).
I had this already working some weeks ago (also with alots of trouble). This 'old' Version dir work, and now it doesn't work anymore. It just delivers the first image in a selection (Rng as Selection) but not for the rest. The MS-Error codes are as usual useless at all.